# Filling up a list with certain cells from other worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a newbie and got I guess a rather simple question: I have a range (S22:S124) in worksheet 2 where the cells take a certain (individual) value if they meet a certain condition, else the cells are set to 0. So far so good.

I now do have a blank list in workheet 1 (Range B14:B53) which I want to fill up with each cell value in range S22:S124 (in worksheet 2), which is non zero (Usually there wont be more than 30 cells that meet this condition, that’s why the range of worksheet 1 only covers around 50 cells). Can you help me out on how a macro would look like, which fills up the list in worksheet 1 with those non zero cell values from list 2?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Are you looking for unique values? Or just all values that are non-zero? Are we talking numeric values or text? What have you tried? Please include your attempt (no matter how bad) in your question.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! I’m looking for all numeric values, that are non zero (they are all positive)! I tried the following, which only fills up the list with the first non zero value from worksheet 2!

For Each cell In Range("S22:S124").Cells

    If cell.Value > 0 Then

        cell.Select

        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("worksheet1").Select

        Range("B14:B53").Activate

        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    End If

Next cell